# Running Flask for the first time

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to all of this and was simply trying to get Flask working with a simple Hello World.  I've pip installed Flask 1.1.1 and running Python 3.7.2.  When I open the file by typing hello.py into Windows cmd, it opens my file in VSCode, but nothing else happens.  The cursor just hangs in the cmd window, then printed:

> [main 2019-12-04T19:26:04.241Z] update#setState idle
>
> [main 2019-12-04T19:26:34.244Z] update#setState checking for update
>
> [main 2019-12-04T19:26:34.352Z] update#setState idle

... and nothing happens.  I don't get an IP address and I've tried opening my browser to the expected 127.0.0.1:5000 but nada.  Any suggestions?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: In Windows, run it as `python hello.py`.

Comment: ugh.  I knew it was something dumb.  Thanks :)